# Jquery plugin to slideshow many images and with small loading time.

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, load, html

Is there any **Jquery**  **Plugin** that can load lot of images **(100-200)** and display each image on browser for **10 secs**? I dont want to **load** all images together as it would take too much time and **webpage** would be very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this jQuery Plugin [Nivo Slider](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider) that may help you. It is customisable as your requirement.

Comment: i checked it.. Have you used it.? Can you tell me how does it work? What are its features? What is the loading quality of this plugin? Thnks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I used it. It is nice and easy to use. You don't worry about loading quality. All the images are loaded as it is and animate as your configure its settings and all other functionality.